# Storing pid of GenServer for future use

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gen-server

I need to start the GenServer at the time of Application start, however its PID will be required to call and cast Genserver. How will i obtain that in the rest of the application for future uses.

Comment: How about creating a named `GenServer`? See the `:name` option in `GenServer.start_link/3`.

Comment: Storing `PID` is generally not a good idea, because `PID` does not survive crashes, while `name` does.

Comment: @Dogbert thank you. Will use :name

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If GenServer will die and will be re-started by a supervisor it will receive new pid and your "stored" one will not be valid anymore - you will not be able to access your GenServer. This is why you should use name here:

`{:ok, _} = GenServer.start_link(MyApp, [:hello], name: :your_genserver_name)`

Then the call / cast would look like:

```
  def get_state do
    GenServer.call(:your_genserver_name, {:get_state})
  end
```

Please refer [this](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration) part of the docs for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Will use name

Comment: Yea sure. Thanks

Comment: Plz note that we usually use `__MODULE__` as name.

Comment: Of course, `__MODULE__` is a common convention and I'm using it often. Everything depend on the use case and simple atom as a name is also perfectly valid. Module name is in the end atom as well.